# PostgreSQL SELECTs not returning correct result following recovery?

Tags: postgresql, replication, index, backup, recovery

I took a copy of the current database from a live slave using `pg_basebackup` and recovered it to a brand new isolated computer following the instructions in the docs. Once the new database had started up, I could see everything was present and had been restored OK, but some simple SELECT queries were failing (returning 0 results), specifically:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address='me@example.com';
```

However, some email addresses ***did*** work. The fix for it was a `REINDEX` on the email address index. Now, the manual says in the caveats section that hash indexes aren't transferred across in the WAL logs, so any slaves won't get the updates and also following recovery, a `REINDEX` should be done, but my index is a B-Tree and nothing is mentioned about that.

1. What is happening?
2. I don't see this on the live slave (connected to master in streaming replication) at the minute, will I in the future?

---

Systems:

Live M/S: CentOS 6.6, with PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit

Isolated Machine: OS X 10.1, PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn), 64-bit

---

CentOS:

```
production=# explain analyse verbose select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';

QUERY PLAN                                                                
----------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using users_email_address_key on hive.users  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.044..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: user_id
   Index Cond: (users.email_address = 'me@example.com'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.093 ms
(4 rows)

production=# select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';
 user_id 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

Mac OS X:

```
production=> explain analyse verbose select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';

QUERY PLAN                                                                
----------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using users_email_address_key on hive.users  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: user_id
   Index Cond: (users.email_address = 'me@example.com'::text)
 Total runtime: 0.031 ms
(4 rows)

production=> select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';
 user_id 
---------
(0 rows)
```

**following the re-index:**

```
production=# reindex index hive.users_email_address_key;
production=# explain analyse verbose select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';
QUERY PLAN                                                
------------------
 Seq Scan on hive.users  (cost=0.00..1.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=0 loops=1)
   Output: user_id
   Filter: (users.email_address = 'me@example.com'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 33
 Total runtime: 0.045 ms
(5 rows)

production=# select user_id from hive.users where email_address='me@example.com';
 user_id 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

Comment: It might happen if the new machine/OS uses different sort rules. Locales are not necessarily portable across machines and so postgres data files aren't either. Please provide more details about your operating systems and postgres version.

Comment: Ahh, I've read of problems with different versions and Linux->Windows but didn't see any problems with mine. I've added in the system information, they are different OSs, so I hope that's the right answer. I'll try with pg_dump and tell you what happens...

Comment: If you still have the original database, please have a look at the execution plan of the querie above. If a reindex on the used index fixes the issue, this might indicate a corruption problem. Could you please add the minor version number of your database ?

Comment: @KookieMonster I've added in the versioning and the query output.

Comment: @Alex ok thanks. Keep a physical backup of your files and rebuild users_email_address_key. Have a look at the index plan and see if your query gives back the same result.

Comment: @KookieMonster I've added in the new stuff, totally different! Do you know what it means, can you give me the 101 on Index Scan vs Seq Scan?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you still get 0 rows when you execute the query on the MAC after the reindex? Please also do an ANALYZE on this table to make sure you don't have old statistics.

Comment: @KookieMonster no, I get the correct result back after the REINDEX. The autovacuum starts at the beginning, so that should be doing the stats update anyway.

Comment: @Alex might have been a corruption issue. As far as I know, autovacuum won't update stats and these are 2 different jobs. Have you updated pg from a previous version? There were bugs in the streaming replication in previous versions (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Nov2013ReplicationIssue for example)

Answer (score 2):

The index data order on disk for text columns depends on the locales provided by the underlying operating system.

The same locales (that is, with the same name) may differ between operating systems on the order rules, even on simple things. As an example this question:
[PostgreSQL 9.1 streaming replication problem: replica fails to use an index properly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35902) 
shows how `"0102"`and `0102`sort differently on Ubuntu and FreeBSD.

The result in the physical index structure is that one value should come before the other in one OS and vice-versa in the other.

The problem with a recovered base backup is the same as with replication: the on-disk structure of the index is used as-is, resulting in a corrupted index in the target system if the column's locale doesn't sort exactly the same between systems.

It's mentioned in the comments that the origin system is CentOS and destination Mac OS X. Given that CentOS uses GNU libc and Mac OS X certainly a BSD-like libc, I'd think that there is no chance at all for on-disk postgres portability between these systems.

Comment: Very interesting, seems like a substantial limitation. I never liked the idea that Postgres relies on the OS for locales and sorting...

Comment: How does the order being different mean it wouldn't get returned at all? It won't check a branch of the B-Tree because it thinks it isn't there or something?

Comment: @Alex: that, and with a higher probability within a b-tree node when doing a binary search, any comparison that yields a different result than when putting the value in will move the "search pointer" in the wrong direction.